# Mockstrutstestcase testing Struts 1.2 App

Tags: java, unit-testing, struts

I am using strutstestcase for testing my web application on struts 1.2.
When test runs and control goes to my action the request.getSession(false), i called in my action, returns null.

could Anyone one help me what i am missing ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was at my end. I am calling `request.getSession(false)` which returns null if session is not exist. `request.getSession()` gives me session and code works.